# I am trying to write a program that will interleave a list which contains a pair of lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a program that will interleave a list which contains a pair of lists?

```
def interleave(lst):
    if lst==[]:
        return []
    return lst.insert(lst[1][0],lst[0][1])+interleave(lst[1][1:])
```

Comment: Gosh, this must be a homework assignment. Let me get you the dupe.

Comment: @Martijn surprised there's not a `roundrobin` itertools recipe in either of those...

Comment: @JonClements: Nah, I didn't think about the `roundrobin` itertools recipe when I answered those.

Comment: input:>>> interleave([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]) [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]

Comment: I have to write it recursively

Comment: think it through - final line should be this instead: return [lst[0][0],lst[1][0]] + interleave([[lst[0][1:],lst[1][1:]])

Comment: Tom McClure. Thanks a mil, I never thought of like that

Comment: Not a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

Think it through - final line should be this instead:

```
return [lst[0][0],lst[1][0]] + interleave([[lst[0][1:],lst[1][1:]])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the input is, but I assume you mean that the input is something like
    [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]
with output of
    [(4,1),(5,2),(6,3)]

for this:

```
def interleave(lst):
  return zip(lst[1], lst[0])
```

You can swap the order of `lst[1]` and `lst[0]` if you want the opposite order.